# Content Editor for Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system

I've created a website for a client of mine. It is coded in ASP.NET with C# and hosted on GoDaddy. She requires this website to updated daily by her. However, this client has very little knowledge of how to edit HTML or text within a site. I don't want to edit it every time she wants an update on the site.

What would be the best solution to my problem? I have looked up Content Management Systems, but I'm a little confused by what exactly it does in terms of coding and the management of the existing site. Does it require me to reformat the whole site to follow the CMS's 'templates'? Would it be better for me design my own back-end panel for her to edit the content (this would obviously take significant work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with a site you're developing from scratch, I'd use the [HtmlEditor](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) from the AjaxControlToolkit or a similar control, and store the html content in the database.

Then, when outputting the html from the database to the client pages, I'd make sure to use the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) to sanitize the html using the `GetHtmlFragment()` function (since this is tagged asp.net).  It's not that much work, actually, if you design the database correctly, and if you've got the skills.

CMS systems are (trying not to oversimplify) entire web sites that are already built and allow people to edit the content using built-in content editing functionality.  They range in functionality and extensibility from  a "You get what you get and there's very little you can change" to "You can customize the heck out of it and buy or build your own modules to extend functionality."  There are a lot of good ones out there, some free, and some expensive.

Comment: You're right; I guess I'm just being lazy. I kept thinking to myself there must be a better way :p. Thanks David, I appreciate your advice.